# Git - Aggregate commits to alternate repo exceed 100MB (one file)

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have an open-sourced project that I do a considerable amount of work on and push to an internal repository, frequently.

The front-end code in this project is transpiled into a single javascript file and its changes are part of every commit. (As an aside, after I transpile and minify the file, it is roughly 3MB in size)

When I am ready to push all of my commits to the open-source community (Github), the aggregate commits for this file are greater than 100MB. Github will not allow me push all of my changes due to the aggregate size of these commits being greater than 100MB.

As a workaround, I have been using [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove this one file from all commits except for the most current commit. Is there a better solution to fixing this issue? I still need to be able to commit internally many times before pushing to open-source (Github).

Comment: have you considered splitting that one monster file into multiple ones? I'd think that might help in other areas as well.

Comment: This is why I recommend against versioning large artifacts along with git sources.

Comment: Which open-sourced project?